# quadratic formula question deriving from completing the square

Tags: quadratics

If you derive the quadratic formula by completing the square on a general quadratic, then should the denominator end up as $2 \ \text{modulus(a)}$ where $a$ is the coefficient on the $x^2$ term which may well be negative?

I know it doesn't matter in the end because of the plus/minus.  thanks

Comment: You've answered your own question: it doesn't matter. I'd prefer just $a$, not $|a|$, which would make most readers think twice to no purpose.

Comment: `I know it doesn't matter in the end` It *does* in fact matter in the end, since replacing the denominator with $\,2|a|\,$ can potentially change the sign of the entire roots, not just the radical. For example, take $\,a=-1\,$, $b=3\,$, $c=-2\,$ then the equation is $\,-x^2 + 3 x - 2 = 0\,$ with roots $\,\frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{3^2- 4 \cdot 2}}{2 \,\cdot\, (-1)} = \{1,2\}\,$. If, instead, you replace the denominator with $\,2\cdot|-1|\,$, then the formula gives the (wrong) roots $\,\{-1,-2\}\,$.

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand the last part of the derivation then on the denominator it has principal root(4a^2) which I think defines the same function as 2a for a>0 only. Can you explain what I'm not seeing, thanks

Comment: the reason it did not work there was because of the form. It works in the form...   -b/2a      +/-         principalroot(b^2-4ac)/2mod(a)  exuse my bad formatting. In the derivation however they seem to just use 2a and then combine the terms and it seems to work ok, don't know why though

Comment: @JamesAnthony `don't know why though` That's because $\,\pm a = \pm |a|\,$ in the sense of sets of values.

Comment: Think about what happens to the $\pm$ when you negate the denominator.

Comment: thanks for the help isee it now